# Laravel format DateTime from database result

Tags: mysql, laravel, datetime, time

My database stores two dates in the mysql DateTime format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`. When I get this data (with other strings etc), I want to convert it to another format, maybe `DD.MM.YYYY HH:MM:SS` and display it on my view in a table cell. My database dates are called `date_begin` and `date_end`.

Better, when I get this dates from database, convert it to `DD.MM.YYYY` format, separate the date and the time, store the time in a custom string ("HH1:MM1 - HH2:MM2") and bring both on my view.

How can I achieve this? I found some examples to convert on the view, not in the controller, but I think this is not good for MVC.

Comment: It's usually not good to do hefty data sorting in the view, but light formatting is arguably view's job.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Not sure where you've gotten the impression that *"formatting the date in the view is not good for MVC"*, because that's **not a problem** whatsoever.

If you're using [Eloquent Models](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent) you can do it very easily:

**1.** Add the columns to the `$dates` property in your model class:

```php
protected $dates = ['date_begin', 'date_end'];
```

This will ensure that the values get [mutated](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators) to [Carbon instances](http://carbon.nesbot.com/).

**2.** In your view files you can use the `format` method that Carbon offers like so:

```php
<!-- To use only the date with the given format -->
{{ $item->date_begin->format('Y.m.d') }}

<!-- To use only the time with the given format -->
{{ $item->date_begin->format('H:i:s') }}

<!-- To use both date and time with the given format -->
{{ $item->date_begin->format('Y.m.d H:i:s') }}
```

There's no need to split the value in time and date, just show what you want from the DateTime value using whatever [format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php#refsect1-datetime.createfromformat-parameters) you want.

---

If you're not using Eloquent models, then you can manually use Carbon to format your value like so:

```php
{{ Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $item->date_begin)->format('Y.m.d') }}
```

Comment: Oh, very good, that worked too. I thought, I should do it in the controller. :D  Thank you very much!

Comment: This solution is deprecated since Laravel 7.

Answer (score 11):

I have used the PHP solution without Carbon:

Get the database date as you do (with the default format: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS) and when you print it on your view replace `$item->date_begin` 
to:

```
date('d-m-Y H:i:s', strtotime($item->date_begin))
```

After that, when you save it on the database add on the DB update:

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($request->date_begin))
```

Answer (score 5):

```
protected $casts = [
         'inicio'  => 'datetime:Y-m-d\TH:i'
        ,'entrega'  => 'datetime:Y-m-d\TH:i'
   ];
```

you could use it for the datetime-local field. greed you. like me if work for you

Answer (score 1):

// attributes that should be cast to native types

```
 protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime'
    ];


// get formatted datetime string for email_verified_at

public function getEmailVerifiedAttribute()
 {
        if ($this->email_verified_at) {
            $date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $this->email_verified_at, 'UTC');
            return $date->setTimezone($this->timezone->name)->isoFormat('LLLL');
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

as Laravel document way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this in blade file

```
{{date('Y-m-d',strtotime($invoice->invoice_created_date))}}
```

use date function to fix this issue